# Construct matrix with columns of data and zeros, without using for-loop

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of numerical data with pesky zero columns I want to remove to do some data processing. I keep track of what columns are zero columns with `is_zero_column <- colSums(matrix) == 0` and remove the zero columns via `matrix <- matrix[,colSums(matrix)!=0]`

Now how would I do the reverse, where I use my `is_zero_column` of TRUE/FALSE (TRUE if zero column) to reinsert the zero columns back into my matrix?

If this were not R, I would go for a forloop where I construct a new matrix: (in python-ish pseudocode)

```
new_matrix;
for i in is_zero_column:
  if i is TRUE:
    new_matrix <- new_matrix.append_column(rep(0, columnlength))
  else:
    new_matrix <- new_matrix.append_column(matrix[,1])
    matrix <- matrix[,-1]
return new_matrix;
```

But, this is R, so trying to find a non for loop way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say if `Q` is the matrix without zero columns:

```
Q
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    0    0
#[3,]    0    1
```

And `is_zero_column` is as follows:

```
is_zero_column = c(F,T,F)
```

You can create a zero matrix with number of rows equal to number of rows in Q, and number of columns equal to length of `is_zero_column` vector and then update non zero columns values with values in `Q`:

```
Q1 = matrix(0, nrow(Q), length(is_zero_column))
Q1[, !is_zero_column] = Q
Q1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    1
```

Comment: great, thanks!!  let me know if you care to share any insights. seems like in R, you start with the form of your data structure and then find ways of selecting and modifying rows/columns to conform to your logic.